# How can I submit the values to backend from frontend(react) selected by the user through radio buttons?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend, mern

Here i passed the value to a component to render the values fetched from backend

```
 render() {
    const questions = this.state.questions.map((question) => {
      return (
        <UserTestCard
          questions={question.question}
          optionA={question.options[0].A}
          optionB={question.options[0].B}
          optionC={question.options[0].C}
          optionD={question.options[0].D}
          marks={question.marks}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Jumbotron className="test-details">
          <h4 className="display-3 test-name">
            Name : {this.state.details.name}
          </h4>
          <h4 className="test-status">Status : {this.state.details.status}</h4>
          <h4 className="test-status">
            Subject : {this.state.details.subject}
          </h4>
          <p className="test-id">ID : {this.state.details._id}</p>
        </Jumbotron>
        <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
          {questions}
          <Button>Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
```

Here i render all the values got from the above component but i am unable to post request to the backend through the radio buttons which i clicked

```
return (
      <form>
        <p>Question:{this.props.questions}</p>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={this.props.optionA}
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === this.props.optionA}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
            />
            A: {this.props.optionA}
          </label>
        </div>
```

This is how i should post to backend

```
{   
    "email":"a@a.com",
    "answers":["A","B","A"]
}
```

Comment: `["A","B","A"]` How does user select same radio (`A)` twice? Do you have data in this format already in `this.formSubmit` method?

Comment: Actually in this array its the answer of three questions which user will select from the 4 options ["A","B","C","D"] and then after selecting the three radio buttons from 4 question user will submit  the data in ["A","B","A"] this format.

Comment: Imo for multiple choice answers you should use checkboxes. Also you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send data to backend

Answer (score 0):

You should init answers empty array in state, and later onChange method on options, push each value to the array.

Considering you are using class component:

```
class Example {

    this.state = {answers: []}

    onValueChange(e) {
        let answers = this.state.answers;
        answers.push(e.target.value)
        this.setState({answers});
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, we have to post the answers like this but i want to know to get that values from the radio buttons

Comment: @Shuvam, you need to call this method onValueChange on radio buttons onChange; like this:
`code`
<input
              type="radio"
              value={this.props.optionA}
              checked={this.state.selectedOption === this.props.optionA}
              onChange={this.onValueChange}
`code`
if the option is already selected, by this: {this.state.selectedOption === this.props.optionA}, push all correct answers when component is mounted